# Update specific tapped marker.userdata values for given keys

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, updates

I am using userdata to add custom data to my google maps markers. I am setting the marker.userdata through a class which I have created. Since I have many markers, I am assigning dictionary variables to the class and then assigning that information to userdata.

My question is, once I have tapped on the marker and displayed my userdata in a label, a user can change a textfield to which I want that label to be set. How do I update/ refresh/ reset a particular userdata value specifically for that tapped marker?

setting the class

```
    class markerUserData{
var nameUserData: String
var tags: String

init(Name: String, Tags: String) {
    self.nameUserData = Name
    self.tags = Tags
}
```

creating the markers.userdata

```
    for p in STOREDPlaces {

            let name = p["StoredPlaceName"] as? String
            let tags = p["Tags"] as? Strin
            markers.map = self.vwGMap
            self.vwGMap.setNeedsDisplay()

            let storedPlaceUserData = markerUserData(Name: name!, Tags: tags!)
           markers.userData = storedPlaceUserData
        }
```

the tapped function

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

        detailsName.text = (marker.userData as! markerUserData).nameUserData
 tagsMarker = (marker.userData as! markerUserData).tags
    }

    @IBAction func editingTextField(_ sender: Any) {
  //So in here i want something which will update (marker.userData as! markerUserData).tags and set it to whatever has been edited 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest is to read the Official Google Documentation for [Places API for IOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details), the Google Places API for IOS provides information about places including the place's name and address.

A place ID is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. In the Google Places API for iOS, you can retrieve the ID of a place from a GMSPlace object. You can store the place ID and use it to retrieve the [GMSPlace](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place) object again later.

To get a place by ID, call [GMSPlacesClient lookUpPlaceID:callback:](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client), passing a place ID and a callback method.

The API invokes the specified callback method, passing in a GMSPlace object. If the place is not found, the place object is nil.

```
let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"

GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }

  if let place = place {
    print("Place name \(place.name)")
    print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
    print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
  } else {
    print("No place details for \(placeID)")
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but I have read through these documents over and over. What I am confused about is in the above example the placeID is known (the "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs") whereas with the autocomplete method I'm using obviously the placeID variable is always changing so then would I make it var placeID = GMSPlace.placeID or how? Or did I need to do autocomplete with a fetcher?

Answer (score 0):

To Find a Particular position on Google Map. We use google map tracking. For more info you can go [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details)

A place ID is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. In the Google Places API for iOS, you can retrieve the ID of a place from a GMSPlace object. You can store the place ID and use it to retrieve the GMSPlace object again later.

To get a place by ID, call GMSPlacesClient lookUpPlaceID:callback:, passing a place ID and a callback method.

The API invokes the specified callback method, passing in a GMSPlace object. If the place is not found, the place object is nil.

```
// Here use your placeID
let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"

placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }

  guard let place = place else {
    print("No place details for \(placeID)")
    return
  }

  print("Place name \(place.name)")
  print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
  print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
  print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
})
```

The following code sample retrieves the list of places where the device is most likely to be located, and logs the name, likelihood, and other details for each place.

```
placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }

  if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
    for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods {
      let place = likelihood.place
      print("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
      print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
      print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
      print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")
     }
  }
})
//Add a marker
//To add a marker, create a GMSMarker object that includes a position and title, and set its map.
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10, longitude: 10)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.map = mapView
```